Let $\gamma=\lim_{k\rightarrow1}\sum_{t=1}^\infty k\frac{(kt+k-1)(t+1)^{1/k}-k(t+1)t^{1/k}}{(k-1)t(t+1)}$, is it easier to see if $\gamma\in\Bbb{Q}$?
Does This Simplified Expression of the Euler-Mascheroni Constant Aid in Proving Its Rationality or Transcendence?
When I say "simplified", I mean that it doesn't contain Euler's number, the gamma function, logarithms, pi, complex numbers, primes, factorials, the floor function, integrals, the Riemann zeta function, double series or nested summations. I thought that removing all of these things from an expression of gamma might make analysis a little easier.
I am working on a Wolfram worksheet, but for now...
a Desmos walkthrough

Please use MathJax.

I've modified the title to use MathJax.  I may (probably, in fact) have changed the meaning of the expression in doing so.  You should check that I haven't changed its meaning.  (Note that limits in math and Mathematica are two-sided by default, so you don't need to supply Direction -> $\pm$1.)

I might move the expression for $\gamma$ to the body of the Question:  The title is not read as the first sentence of the Question, it is read as a summary and is intended to appear that way in other contexts.  The Question should contain the information needed to understand it (not have some of that information appear only in the title).  I would also explain why you think this expression for $\gamma$ might make it easier to resolve the rationality of $\gamma$.

First thought: every real number is a limit of rationals.  You have written a limit of a limit of rationals -- why is this more (or less) likely to land on a rational (or not)?

Thank you,  the title looks fine.
